# How to upload image using App42

Tags: android, asp.net-web-api, app42

I have a WebApi project and a Android client, and I need to upload some images from the WebApi using App42, the problem is, in [this](http://api.shephertz.com/tutorial/Saving-Binary-Data-(Files)/) tutorial, it must have a StringPath, but I dont have a stringPath, because the image is gonna be send by the Android Client for the Api and then Save those images. Do I have to send the image from Android as Base64 and then create a tempFileObject as Bitmap and then put the stringPath?

```
String name = "MyPic";    
String userName = "Nick";    
String filePath = " file path from gallery /sd card";   
String fileType = "IMAGE";    
String description = "This is my holiday pic";  
Upload upload = uploadService.UploadFileForUser(name,userName,filePath,fileType,description);    
// File will get uploaded in App42 cloud with above snippet.      
IList<Upload.File> fileList =  upload.GetFileList();  // This will have only single file uploaded above  
for (int i = 0; i < fileList.Count; i++)    
{    
    Console.WriteLine("fileUrl is " + fileList[i].GetUrl());    
    //This will return uploaded file URL  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the query then you don't have file saved in the device local file storage. If Yes, then you can use [another API](http://api.shephertz.com/app42-docs/file-upload-service/#upload-file-with-input-stream) which will ask you the InputSteam of the image as parameter.

I hope this helps.